# Lock image size on Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, video, matlab-figure

I'm making a GUI in MatLab that asks the user to upload a video file. 
Next I want to play it in axes with a fixed window size . However, if the uploaded file is large, Matlab will expand the axes and take over most of my GUI. Is there a way to shrink the image to make it fit the axes?

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually Matlab axes are not supposed to change their position if the image is too big.

I can think of two possible problems:

1. The axes were large from the beginning, but showed small image with margins if the image is small enough
2. The command of showing the image that you are using is custom and it changes the axes size.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I stumbled across this (looking for something else) so perhaps it will help someone to see what I did.

I wanted to resize pretty large images (1024x 100k-200k pixels) so that my GUI can quickly demonstrate various color operations on a view of these large data sets.  I just manually sub-sampled my data as follows (functions below).

Note that this example is an image.  To spatially sub-sample a video, I have looped through the video and done something similar in the past on each frame.

```
[plotWidthPixels, plotHeightPixels] = getPlotAreaPixels(handles.figure1, handles.axes1);

[nSamplesPerLine nLines] = size(iqData);
colInds = decimateToNumber(nLines,plotWidthPixels);
rowInds = decimateToNumber(nSamplesPerLine,plotHeightPixels);
iqDataToPlot = iqData(rowInds,colInds);
```

First, I got the axis size in pixels:

```
function  [plotWidthPixels, plotHeightPixels] = getPlotAreaPixels(figHandle, axisHandle)
set(figHandle,'Units','pixels')
figSizePix = get(figHandle,'Position');

set(axisHandle,'Units','normalized')
axSizeNorm = get(axisHandle,'Position');

axisSizePix = figSizePix.*axSizeNorm;
plotWidthPixels = ceil(axisSizePix(3)-axisSizePix(1));
plotHeightPixels = ceil(axisSizePix(4)-axisSizePix(2));
```

Then I used that to decimate the width and height of my image by getting sub-sets of indices that are (crudely approximately) evenly spaced:

```
function inds = decimateToNumber(lengthOfInitialVector, desiredVectorLength, initialIndex)
if nargin < 3
    initialIndex = 1;
end

if (lengthOfInitialVector-initialIndex+1) > desiredVectorLength*2
    inds = round(linspace(initialIndex,lengthOfInitialVector,desiredVectorLength));
else
    inds = initialIndex:lengthOfInitialVector;
end
```